# libltdl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04, libltdl

I have a program the requires shared library libltdl.so.3. While running this program in 14.04 i am encountering following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libltdl.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have libtool already install and updated. While running atp-get install libltdl3 i get following output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libltdl3 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libltdl3' has no installation candidate
```

While running locate libltdl.so i get

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.0
```

Can someone tell me how to get libltdl.so.3?

Comment: One thing you can try is to created a symbolic link of `libltdl.so.7` to `libltdl.so.3`, which is [reported to work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=978407&p=6343030#post6343030)

Comment: Did the answer work for you? Do let us know

Comment: Yes, It did. Marked as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I found is to create a symlink

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.3
```

See: http://englanders.us/~jason/howtos.php?howto=libtool